# How to get the first element of a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, microsoft-metro

I remember seen some code xaml where can get the first element (like an index x[0]) from a collection.

This is my CollectionViewSource from Resources.

```
<CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource2"
            Source="{Binding Posters}"
            ItemsPath="Posters" />
```

If I display this in a listbox, it loaded it!

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource2}}" />
```

But right now, I just want to get the first element through xaml. Is it possible doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced similar issue, and what i did was to call [`MoveCurrentToFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrenttofirst%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in ViewModel)

[`SelectedIndex=0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
(on ListBox in XAML), was another way but it was failing when Collection view source does not hold any data.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I have found so far is to go via enumerator:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observable);
var enumerator = view.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext(); // sets it to the first element
var firstElement = enumerator.Current;
```

or you can do the same with an extension and call it directly on the observable collection:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T First<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observableCollection);
        var enumerator = view.GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        T firstElement = (T)enumerator.Current;
        return firstElement;
    }
}
```

and then call it from the observable collection:

```
var firstItem = observable.First();
```

Comment: To get the first visible element of the collection (not the underlying data) this is the way to go IMHO. Although if you use the extension method I would name it like `FirstInView` or something like that to make clear we are accessing the collection view and not the (observable) colleciton itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of accomplishing this that I know of. I'd probably go with either a separate property that returns the first of the collection, or create a Converter that will return the first element in any collection or list it is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous response, you should use `ICollectionView` instance. You can get one by calling

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observable);
```

And create extension method (using c# langversion 9.0):

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    public static class ICollectionViewExtensions
    {
        public static bool TryGetFirstInView<T>(this ICollectionView self, [NotNullWhen(true)] out T? item)
        {
            var enumerator = self.GetEnumerator();
            if (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.Current is T current)
            {
                item = current;
                return true;
            }
            
            item = default;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```